# Incorrect display dimensions for Android OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using the `DisplayMetrics` to get the display dimensions of the Android phone as follow:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Results give me `height=854, width=480`.

When I want the viewport to cover the whole screen as below, the viewport does not cover the complete display.

```
GLES20.glViewport(0,0,480,854);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Any explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the quad does not cover the whole screen. OpenGL screen coordinates range from -1 to 1 on both axis. Make sure the quad has a width and height of 2 if your not using a projection matrix. If you are using a projection matrix adjust the projection matrix parameters to project the quad on the entire screen or scale the quad to fit the the screen with current projection matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a better idea to get screen width and height from [onSurfaceChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onSurfaceChanged(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10,%20int,%20int)) since it takes orientation under account (and is called when it changes).
What does it mean does not cover the whole display? If it is the status bar and navigation bar that "take" screen space then you can [hide](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#sticky) them.

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: Tried the code you suggested.  Gives me error that permissions denied to  change the views on another thread that created the views.  Also, please find the attached screenshot in original message.

Comment: Also please note, I would like the opengl viewport to cover the whole screen but the dimensions I get from the code above does not do it. Are they not supposed to give the absolute resolutions in pixels?  Also, I do not have any navigation or other widgets.

Comment: @KaleemPeeroo The code above should be written in the Activity class on the onCreate method. By the screenshot you added It seems the viewport is covering the whole screen (by the purple background). It looks like the problem is that the quad is not big enough. By default the coordinates of opengl are -1 to 1 on both axis. Make sure you make the quad bigger to cover the whole screen. If you want the screen to be in different coordinate you should look at an ortho matrix

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Yes, your code goes in the onCreate all right.  I had the quad coordinates from -1 to 1 on both axis and is the region covered by the texture.  The problem was the Projection Matrix.  I changed the Matrix and it does cover the whole screen now.  Thanks for your kind info and help.

Comment: Can you add a Projection Matrix to define the whole screen and I can check your reply as an answer above?

Comment: Great!!! However the projection matrix does not define how much of the screen is used for opengl, it just maps virtual coordinates to screen coordinates that are from -1 to 1.